# How do I copy all instances of a keyword from a dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame A -

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

data = ['mechanical@engineer', 'field engineer','lab_scientist', 'doctor', 'computer-engineer', 'scientist/engineer']# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job'])

print("df = ", df.head())
```

Let's say I have a list with the keywords - `[engineer, scientist]`. I want to create another dataframe B from dataframe A containing A's rows like this -

```
     Keyword                  Job
0   engineer  mechanical@engineer
1   engineer       field engineer
2   engineer    computer-engineer
3   engineer   scientist/engineer
4  scientist        lab_scientist
5  scientist   scientist/engineer
```

I am not really sure how to proceed. Here is my strategy -
I could start by looping over the list and then looping over dataframe A and doing a `str.contains()`. However, I am not sure how to copy the rows over to another dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.str.extractall`:

```py
df['Keyword'] = df["Job"].str.extractall(r"(?i)(engineer|scientist)").groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df.explode('Keyword'))
```

Prints:

```
                   Job    Keyword
0  mechanical@engineer   engineer
1       field engineer   engineer
2        lab_scientist  scientist
3               doctor        NaN
4    computer-engineer   engineer
5   scientist/engineer  scientist
5   scientist/engineer   engineer
```

---

If you don't want to have `NaN`:

```py
df['Keyword'] = df["Job"].str.extractall(r"(?i)(engineer|scientist)").groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df.explode('Keyword').dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Prints:

```
                   Job    Keyword
0  mechanical@engineer   engineer
1       field engineer   engineer
2        lab_scientist  scientist
3    computer-engineer   engineer
4   scientist/engineer  scientist
5   scientist/engineer   engineer
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
keywords = ['engineer', 'scientist']
pat = rf"({'|'.join(keywords)})"
df['Keyword'] = df['Job'].str.extract(pat)
```

---

```
                   Job    Keyword
0  mechanical@engineer   engineer
1       field engineer   engineer
2        lab_scientist  scientist
3               doctor        NaN
4    computer-engineer   engineer
5   scientist/engineer  scientist
```